# One problem about a barrier

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have two points $A(0,0)$ and $B(L,0)$ on a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $AB$ is a perpendicilar bisector of a straight barrier $\Omega=\{\ (x,y)\ |\ x=L/2,y\in [-\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2}] \}$, also, $A$ and $B$ are standing on equal distances from $\Omega$. So, let us call the middle point of $\Omega$ $O(L/2,0)$, then $AO=BO=L/2$.

You want to move from $A$ to $B$ by the **shortest** line with **constant velocity**, but your moving point only has information about the barrier in an $\varepsilon$-disc around itself. Thus, the trajectory of a moving point can be determined only in some neighbourhood of a moving point. For example, if $\varepsilon=\infty$ (it means that you can see the straight segment fully), you can move (without loss of generality due to the symmetry within the problem) from $A$ to the 'highest' point of $\Omega$ by a straight segment and then to $B$ in the same manner.

In the case when $\varepsilon=L/2$ (it means that in the beginning of the motion we can see only the middle point of $\Omega$) the problem gets much more interesting! Our point will not be able to move by a straight segment to the peak of $\Omega$ as it will not have the full information about where the peak is. So there appears some curve from $A$ heading to the peak.

The algorithm of finding the desirable path is as following:

1. Move forfard, towards $\Omega$, a bit, by a step $ds$;
2. Find two points (one of which we can omit by the symmetry) of the intersection of the $\varepsilon$-circle (to remind, $\varepsilon=L/2$);
3. From one of the found points build a segment to the point $(ds,0)$;
4. Move a bit, by $ds$, in the direction of the segment built in (3);
5. Repeat (1) to (4).

This way seems to be extra-intuitive and informal.

My question is: how to describe the path in terms of differential equations? I am attaching my considerations below, so feel free to check and fix them.

Let us be searching the path in a parametric form $(x(t),y(t))$. Firstly, $ds=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}dt$. Secondly, by stepping by $ds$ towards $\Omega$ for the first time (at the zero iteration) our $\varepsilon$-circle intersects the barrier in the points $$y=\sqrt{L^2-(L-ds)^2}.$$ Having these facts in the arsenal, we can conclude that at the first iteration we will be moving by the segment $(L-(L-(ds+dx_1))),y-dy_1)$, where $dx_1$ and $dy_1$ stand for the translations in $x$ and $y$ after the zero iteration.

After some algebraic transformations and saying that $dx_1=\dot{x},dy_1=\dot{y}$ I get the following equation: $$\dot{y}-\ddot{y}=\sqrt{2\ddot{x}\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}(L-1)-2\dot{x}\ddot{x}}.$$

But one needs some other equation to make up a system of two equations determine the trajectory.

By the way, at the moment $x_0=L-\sqrt{L^2-a^2/4}$ we will be moving to the peak by a straight segment as at this moment we will be able to see it.[image]

Comment: Your coordinates in the text and the plot do not match. $B(0,L)$ means that $B$ is above $A$ in the figure. Also, you mention that barrier is at $x=L$, but in the figure you put it at $L/2$

Comment: @Andrei I'm sorry, it's a minor mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will adopt you initial strategy, because no better strategy is in sight. That means you move from the point $A$ along the horizontal line until you start seeing the barrier and then you move to the highest *visible* point of the barrier. For the sake of convenience I will denote the length of the barrier as $2a$ and the distance $AB$ as $2L$ and consider only the motion for $x\le L$. The differential equations for the motion in this range of $x$ read:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\begin{cases}
0,& L-x\ge \epsilon;\\
\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-(L-x)^2}}{L-x},&L-x\le\epsilon,\quad (L-x)^2+(a-y)^2\ge\epsilon^2;\\
\frac{a-y}{L-x},& (L-x)^2+(a-y)^2\le\epsilon^2
\end{cases}
$$

The equations can be readily solved. The first and the third equations are the equations of straight lines.

**EDIT:**
The general idea behind the equations is the following. Let the barrier be described by some function $F(x,y)=0$ and let $(X,Y)$ be the point of intersection of the function with the "view circle":
$$\begin{cases}
F(X,Y)=0,\\
(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2=\epsilon^2.
\end{cases}
$$
This should be compared with the "tangent point" when it is inside the view circle. In your original problem it is just the point $(L,a)$. In the case of a smooth curve it can be found from:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{Y-y}{X-x}=\frac{F_x(X,Y)}{F_y(X,Y)}\\
(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2<\epsilon^2.
\end{cases}
$$
In the case of multiple solutions a way to choose the correct one is assumed (for example the solution which makes the largest angle with the horizontal axis when viewed from the current position). As soon as the solution is found the differential equation reads:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{Y-y}{X-x}.
$$
In the case of the tangent point the motion is along straight line. If no barrier is in sight or the point $(X,Y)$ makes smaller (signed!) angle than the direction to the goal (we are on the other side of the barrier!) we simply move along the straight line to the goal.

Comment: How did you make up the main (second) equation? I do not understand the transition between my algorithm and your solution. Did you merely extract the $y(x)$ from a moment when we intersect the barrier with the $\varepsilon$-circle at the first time?

Comment: And what if I want to generalise my barrier to a circle with radius $R$? How would you recommend me to change the equations?

Comment: @DenisD.Bavrin This is the same approach. Let $(X,Y)$ be the intersection point of both circles. Then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{Y-y}{X-x}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hello again. I still do not see clearly how there appears exactly $$\frac{Y-y}{X-x}=\frac{F_x(x,y)}{F_y(x,y)}.$$ Also, what do you mean by 'tangent point'? Do you mean the peak of the obstacle region?

Comment: I mean the point of tangency of the tangent line drawn from the current position to the "barrier".